# Fermi Surface Plots

Tags: python, numpy, 3d, interpolation, surface

Essentially I am trying to do a Fermi Surface plot, in 2D.  i.e. a 2D cut of f(n,vec_k)=e_f for some plane in K-space, with interpolation.  Specifically, I have a numpy array: Eigen, with shape,

Eigen.shape = (100,100,100,10), where the first three indices are over the vector vec_k, and the third is the band index 'n'.  How to get a cut through an arbitrary surface Eigen == e_f, where e_f is a scalar number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally solved using a marching cube algorithm. You should look into `contour3d()` function of `MLab` here: http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#mayavi.mlab.contour3d. THis does exactly what you want.

```
contour3d(Eigen[:,:,:, bandNo], contours=e_f)
```

should do it for you. You can also specify a number of surfaces for all bands like so:

```
for bandNo in range(totalBands):
    contour3d(Eigen[:,:,:, bandNo], contours=[eF1, eF2, eF3], opacity=0.4)
```

You should get plots like these: http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/_images/enthought_mayavi_mlab_contour3d1.jpg

Comment: Thanks. It worked. It was painful to install mayavi, but well worth it.

Comment: If you are using windows, I would recommend Python(x,y). (http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/) It puts everything in one place. Otherwise, if you are in a University, you can try the Enthought distribution that comes with Mayavi. Otherwise, I know the installation procedure is really painful!!